# Simple way to encrpyt/decrypt a number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to encrypt a 2-digit number in a simple way. The samples I found in google seems to be quite complex. Is there any easy way to achieve that?

**UPDATE**

I'm working on a custom numeric captcha for my ASP.NET MVC application. I've created a custom html helper that will render an image tag with base-64 encoded string of the captcha image. The captcha image will be something like `23 + 12 = ?`. When the user submit the answer I want to validate it right? I'm not interested in storing the sum in session so I thought of encrypt the sum and attach as a hidden field and so when the user submit the form I can easily do the validation.

Comment: Have you looked at System.Security.Cryptography?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx

Comment: n+=1. They'll never see it coming.

Comment: @fire.eagle: but then what about 99?

Comment: Why would you encrypt a *2* digit number? That seems sort of pointless.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard if 99 then 00

Comment: are there any other requirements? it seems too simple...

Comment: What kind of encryption key do you want? A string? A number? etc etc

Comment: @Earlz a string `is` a number

Comment: @Andrei in that argument a number is also a string :)

Comment: Just see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200132/encrypting-and-decrypting-numbers-with-net

Answer (score 2):

If your number is `x` then you can encrypt it as `(x + key) mod 100`. This will result in another 2 digit number, `y`.

It doesn't get much simpler than that.

The decryption is simply `x = y - key`,  `+100` if necessary.

If `key` is 2:

```
x = 15
y = 15 + 2 = 17
x = 17 - 2 = 15

x = 99
y = 99 + 2 mod 100 = 101 mod 100 = 1
x = 1 - 2 + 100 = 99;
```

Even simpler would be to encrypt `x` as `x`. They would definitely never expect that...

Edit 1:

On a more serious note, If this is not some sort of personal experiment/homework I'd stay clear of such "simple" algorithms and go with System.Security.Cryptography and those not-that-complex samples from Google or charles sun's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200132/encrypting-and-decrypting-numbers-with-net). Unless you make a carrier out of it never implement you own encryption/decryption algorithms, that way lies madness.

Edit 2:

So you want to send both the captcha and its correct response to the client? I don't think that is how it's done (but then again this is not my field...). I always thought validation is done on the server side (the part you control and keep secure).

To be on the safe side, I would do this the hard way and encrypt everything properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not entirely serious, but it works!

```
  static IEnumerable<string> GetRandomStringsForever()
  {
    var rng = new Random();  // or maybe new Random(14142848)
    while (true)
    {
      char[] arr = new char[8];
      for (int idx = 0; idx < arr.Length; ++idx)
        arr[idx] = (char)rng.Next('A', 'Z' + 1);
      yield return new string(arr);
    }
  }

  static void Main()
  {
    var secretKey = GetRandomStringsForever().Distinct().Take(100).ToList();

    int message = 42;

    // encrypt:
    string cryptic = secretKey[message];

    Console.WriteLine("Who can guess the number from this: " + cryptic);

    // decrypt:
    int reconstructed = secretKey.IndexOf(cryptic);

    Console.WriteLine("The message was: " + reconstructed);

  }
```

Well, if people know you're doing this using my idea, they will probably be able to construct the `secretKey` themselves (using the same version of .NET as you), so this is not REALLY safe.